# How to enable font variant like "Italic Display"

Tags: css, fonts

I've got a font rendered on webkit (specifically in the text editor "Nano") and I'd like to display an OTF font that has a variant called  "Garamond Premier Pro Italic Display". I believe it's a "suitcase" font.

Here's what the font looks like in Font Book:

[image: "Garamond Premier Pro Italic Display"]

Things I've tried:

`font-variant-alternates: character-variant("ItDisp");`

and

`font-variant-alternates: character-variant("Garamond Premier Pro Italic Display");`
No dice.

Any thoughts here? Or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly this is not possible on the web at the time of writing.
The only real options available to use [are as follows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style#Values):

- italic
- normal
- oblique

You can read up on the font-style attribute and the different things you can do with it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style

There are /MANY/ fonts on desktop platforms that simply will not work on the web, as the web use [different file formats.](http://aprcreative.com.au/digital-marketing/web-fonts-vs-desktop-fonts-pt-1/) It is recommended to use fonts that are specifically designed for use on the web.

Also a note that `font-variant-alternates` is [only supported in Firefox 34+ and Safari](https://caniuse.com/#search=font-variant-alternates), and as such should not be used in production.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that wasn't the answer, but that's where my research had been pointing me.